# StreamReader and Condition Statement

Tags: c#, wpf, streamreader, using-statement

I have multiple *.csv text files to check if the first line either starts with "Apple" or "Orange", or the validation returns false. Hence:

```
File#1: Apple, Fruit, Good <-- return true
File#2: Orange, Fruit, Good <-- return true
File#3: Banana, Fruit, Good <-- return false (neither Apple nor Orange)
```

If I combine the operators in a condition within a using statement, I would always get false if the text starts with orange

```
bool myBool = false;
using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader(path, true))
{
    if ((file.ReadLine().Split(',')[0] == "Apple") || (file.ReadLine().Split(',')[0] == "Orange"))
    {
        isValid = true;
    }
}
return myBool;
}

File#1: Apple, Fruit, Good <-- return true
File#2: Orange, Fruit, Good <-- return false (should be true!!)
File#3: Banana, Fruit, Good <-- return false
```

Only if I separate the two conditions into two separate using statement does the code produce the correct result:

```
using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader(path, true))
{
    if ((file.ReadLine().Split(',')[0] == "Apple"))
    {
        isValid = true;
    }
}

using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader(path, true))
{
    if ((file.ReadLine().Split(',')[0] == "Orange"))
    {
        isValid = true;
    }
}
return myBool;
}
```

Would someone help explain why this is happening, as I do not see the difference between the two logic?

Comment: may I know where you are assigning myBool?

Comment: why not use some temp values for debugging and check `Split(',')[0]`?

Answer (score 1):

Your line of code:

```
if ((file.ReadLine().Split(',')[0] == "Apple") || (file.ReadLine().Split(',')[0] == "Orange"))
```

reads two lines from the file.  Line 1 is checked for Apple and line 2 is checked for Orange.

Recommend assigning the ReadLine() to a variable prior to comparison.

```
var fruit = file.ReadLine().Split(',')[0];
if (fruit == "Apple" || fruit == "Orange")
```

Answer (score 0):

You've called `ReadLine()` twice within your `if` statement when I think you only intended it to parse one line at a time there. I would suggest using a variable for the read line before testing it.

```
bool myBool = false;
using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader(path, true))
{
    var line = file.ReadLine();
    var pieces = line.Split(',');
    if (pieces.Length > 0 && (pieces[0] == "Apple") || pieces[0] == "Orange"))
    {
        isValid = true;
    }
}
return myBool;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing in the same file path to check whether it starts with the word 'Apple' or 'Orange'. For example File#1: : Apple, Fruit, Good starts with Apple so it will return True for Apple but not for Orange.

In your modified code, where you have two using statements, First using statement finds the condition true as File#1 starts with 'Apple'. And then it goes to the second Using statement. There is no where else you are changing IsValid to False. Means once it's set to True, it will stay True even for the second using statement and condition inside it.

I have changed 'path' to 'pathToFile1' and 'pathToFile2' for each using statement to make it easier to understand. In this example I am just explaining the problem in your second solution.

```
using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader(pathToFile1, true))
{
    if ((file.ReadLine().Split(',')[0] == "Apple"))
    {
        isValid = true;
    }
    else
        isValid = false;
}

using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader(pathToFile2, true))
{
    if ((file.ReadLine().Split(',')[0] == "Orange"))
    {
        isValid = true;
    }
    else
        isValid = false;
}
return myBool;
}
```

Here is the real solution;

```
    bool myBool = false;
    using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader(path, true))
    {
        var firstWord = (file.ReadLine().Split(',')[0];
        if (firstWord  == "Apple") || (firstWord  == "Orange"))
        {
            isValid = true;
        }
    }
    return myBool;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Each* call to `ReadLine()` reads a (new) line from the file. You should read all lines from the file one by one:

```
using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader(path, true))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        string[] s = line.Split(',');
        if (s.Length > 0 && (s[0] == "Apple" || s[0] == "Orange"))
            isValid = true;
    }
}
```